# </textarea> tag not not showing up

Tags: html, textarea

I'm trying to make myself a file manager, and I managed to make an "edit file" function in PHP. In the main page I do have a textarea, but when I want to edit the main page "source", the text stops exactly where the textarea tag closes (`</textarea>`)

Here's a representation of the problem:

```
<textarea><textarea>Hello World.</textarea></textarea>
```

The textarea output would be

```
<textarea><textarea>Hello World.
```

This is because in the code I've closed the textarea tag, but the browser acts like it's been closed from outside the code.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Sounds like you should read about "html escaping". Well, actually you _have to_, since without you will run into much bigger issues like other people doing with your system whatever they want. In other words: you have a massive security issue here you have to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to encode the inner tags like so:

```html
<textarea>&lt;textarea&gt;Hello World.&lt;/textarea&gt;</textarea>
```

In PHP it's simply a matter of running the file source through `htmlspecialchars()`. A single pass will not alter the output that is displayed in your editor's textarea.

Comment: Awesome! Just tried htmlspecialchars() and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should escape characters that make up a tag, if you don't want it to be a tag.

```
<textarea><textarea>Hello world.&#60/textarea>
```

Or as BoltClock did, esacpe all special characters.

```
<textarea>&lt;textarea&gt;Hello World.&lt;/textarea&gt;</textarea>
```